# how "%c" specification works with scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

I have following code

```
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);
```

Now i have read that "%c" will consume the whitespaces including `ENTER`.But why when i press `ENTER` (before pressing any character) `%c` is not accepting it?

So why it accept the `ENTER` key which is present in the buffer due to previous calls and not accept `ENTER` key before pressing any character?

Comment: Because that's its spec

Comment: The question is nor very clear. Please post a compilable code example and an input sequence that leads to unexpected results.

Comment: The code you posted, with the input `\n`, correctly assigns `'\n'` to `c` (assuming `scanf` doesn't fail).

Comment: "when i press ENTER (before pressing any character) %c is not accepting it?"  Yes it is.  Show more of you code demonstrating why you think it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is about why some inputs, including `Enter`, are not passed to scanf().
It is not about %c or %d or any other type.
You see, those special characters like `Esc` are not passet to the IO functions. However they are recognized by, for instance, Console that opens when executing the code.

Comment: Actually when pressing enter in the console a newline character is sent to the standard input and `scanf` gets it just like any other character.

Comment: Then why don't you see "\n" or whatever the new line character of the current environment or OS in the char &c ?

Comment: If so, I can apologize.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    printf("%d",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

***Output of above program is***:-    (when first key pressed is enter)

**10**

The above program generated 10 because ASCII Code of `'\n'` is 10.

***So for me it even took new line character as first input. ***